# Create Masonry image gallery in pdf or print document format

Tags: image, image-processing, gallery, masonry

I have a lot of situations where I need to print multiple images on a page. Often time I want to create Masonry like layout but I need to manually resize each image to do this and I feel like it is very inefficient.

There are a lot of options to do this on web format on a browser using javascript but are there any way to achieve masonry image gallery look on a print or document format?

I want to be able to just throw in multiple images in to a layout and want the app to resize and position each images to maximize page space like in masonry layout.

Are there any apps that can achieve this easily?

Thank You.